# Set SQL Parameter Value IF IS NULL

Tags: sql

I have parameter and i want to check if length is 0. If it is 0 then Null, else I want the same value ? What idea do you have ?

```
SET @gre = NULLIF(LEN(@gre), 0)
```

Comment: This looks like SQL Server, right? And your solution looks about right and I'm not sure what you can improve on it, except maybe using a `CASE` but that's more code than needed to achieve the same thing.

Comment: `SET @gre = CASE WHEN LEN(@gre) > 0 THEN @gre END`

Answer (score 3):

This should work if it's a VARCHAR:

```
SET @gre = NULLIF(@gre, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SET @gre = 
    case 
        when LEN(@gre) = 0 then NULL
        else @gre
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement:

```
SET @gre = CASE WHEN LEN(@gre) = 0 OR @gre IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE @gre END
```